# Proving an altered converse of Spivak chapter 5 question 31

Tags: calculus, limits

Spivak 5-31:

> Suppose that $$\lim_{x→a^−}f(x)<\lim_{x→a^+}f(x)$$ Prove that there is some $\delta$>0 such that $f(x)<f(y)$ whenever $x<a<y$ and $|x−a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$. Is the converse true?

The proof is not too hard, and we know the converse is not true. But it is claimed that this "edited" converse is true. Instead of strictly lesser than, we have lesser than or equal to.

> If there is some $\delta$>0 such that $f(x)<f(y)$ whenever $x<a<y$ and $|x−a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$, then  $$\lim_{x→a^−}f(x)\leq\lim_{x→a^+}f(x)$$

I do not know how to prove that statement. and I do not think that statement is true as well.

**counter-example:**

$$
f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
0  & \text { if } x \text{ is irrational and } x<1 \\
1  & \text { if } x \text{ is rational and } x<1 \\
2  & \text { if } x \text{ is irrational and } x<1 \\
3  & \text { if } x \text{ is rational and } x>1 \\
    \end{cases}
$$
[image]

Its obvious that $\lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^+}f(x)$ does not exist. But it is true that there is some $\delta$>0 such that $f(x)<f(y)$ whenever $x<a<y$ and $|x−a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$. In fact any $\delta$ will do.

> Is my counter-example valid. How must we loosen the conditions of the converse so that it will be true?

edit: I think the converse is true if $\lim_{x→a^−}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x→a^+}f(x)$ exists. I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: If the one sided limits exist, then yes the weak inequality $\leq$ holds (but the strict inequality $<$ obviously need not hold). This is essentially a form of the squeeze theorem/can be proved similarly to the squeeze theorem.

Comment: peek-a-boo Hm... I'm not sure what you mean